# how do i add the facebook module to android studio

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hi i have been trying to add the facebook sdk to my project in android studio its in my file tree and i can use it limitedly, eg; i can use a facebook login button but if i run the app it crashes at start up, i think i have to import the module for it but android studio wont/cant find it, im still new to android so please tell me if im just missing something simple, here are some screen shots of me going through the motions,

[image]

by right clicking on the project and pressing f4 i go to module settings

[image]
from here i select my project, go to the dependencies tab and select the + from the top right corner

[image],

but this is what i get 
[image]

so my question is should the libraries:facebook be here or am i in the wrong menu? this seems a little different to the tutorials ive been watching but ive put this down to me using android studio 0.5.8 can anybody give me any suggestions as to what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is precisely described here... [using facebook sdk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio)

and here, [How to import a Module on Android Studio 0.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301074/how-to-import-a-module-on-android-studio-0-5-1)

Comment: Not exactly an answer been over these links a lot and they suggest several answers and they suggest if your having other errors post as a new question? Is it the folder needs to be libs and not libraries?

Comment: still going still cant get it to work read that on 0.5.8 you can just import it without messing with anything, unfortunately this hasnt worked either, why is this so difficult?