# How to Import Module without creating copy in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, library-project

I am using Android Studio 1.3.1 and trying to add library module to an existing android application. The library module is available in a git repository. I am able to import the module, but it creates a copy inside the existing app. Hence I am not able to pull the updates in the module.

I am sure there is a way to import external libraries from an existing Android project in studio.

I found the below stackoverflow posts related to my doubt -

1. [How to import a Module on Android Studio 0.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301074/how-to-import-a-module-on-android-studio-0-5-1)
2. [Android Studio 0.8.1 Creating Modules without copying files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files)

Both seem not to work for me. I also found couple of [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658422/android-studio-0-8-1-creating-modules-without-copying-files#comment48541556_24659324) from other users saying it is also not working for them in the latest version of studio.

Here are the things that I tried

```
// in settings.gradle
include ':libraryName'
project(':libraryName').projectDir=new File('/path/to/library')

// in build.gradle
compile project(':libraryName')
```

Also I tried using this [this url](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference without copying a library project on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494105/how-to-reference-without-copying-a-library-project-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 17):

You were on the right track. Just make sure your library is inside one folder then you can direct the library path like this..

Inside settings.gradle

```
include ':libraryName'
project (":libraryName").projectDir = new File("../FolderName/libraryName")
```

if your library is inside 2 folders then direct the path like this...

```
include ':libraryName'
project (":libraryName").projectDir = new File("../../FolderName/libraryName")
```

This allowed me to use the library without making a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Is your path relative or absolute there?

Try this if you want to reference the other module relative to the current project:

```
    include ':libraryName'
    project(':libraryName').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../path/to/library')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the projectDir and by setting the rootProject.name it will also show up in your IDEs Project pane:

```
// in settings.gradle
include ':app'
rootProject.name = "Project name"
include ':libraryName'
project (":libraryName").projectDir = new File("../path/to/library")
```

```
// in build.gradle
compile project(':libraryName')
```

Comment: Worked great, but instead of compile use implementation

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried creating a folder 'libs' under your project and copying the .jar file to that folder and try compile the libs folder? That seems to normally work for me. I think it was the first solution on this question

[How to import a Module on Android Studio 0.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301074/how-to-import-a-module-on-android-studio-0-5-1)