# Import spinnerwheel module to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can i import this library to my project in android studio 
[spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel)

Comment: take a library folder, and use File-New-Import Module, as always

Comment: please give me some steps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170395/how-to-include-a-library-module-dependency-in-an-android-studio-project/21170626#21170626

Comment: there is nothing to give - there's only 1 step - you point a directory, and press finish

Comment: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download that zip from github

You should put your library modules inside the Application Project. In order to specify a module dependency, simply:

1. Right click on Application->Open Module Settings
2. Click on the '+' icon
3. Select the root directory for your library module you'd like to add.
4. Follow the prompts

Then, this module will show up in your project. Then, you need to add it to Application as a library dependency. Once again, in your Module Settings:

1. Select your Application module
2. Select the Dependencies tab on the right
3. Click the '+' icon on the bottom
4. Select Module Dependency
5. Select your desired library module