# How to use module as library in android

Tags: android, github, verification

I am going to use cognalys (third party library) in my app for mobile verification..I cloned that from git hub and i imported that cognalys in my app as module.How to use that module as library in my project(how to convert that as library)..I dont know how to use that..By using that only i can create a class for mobile verification of user...

Please help me to find out the solution

This is my build.gradle of cognalys project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: This link might help you: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a library module dependency in an Android Studio project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170395/how-to-include-a-library-module-dependency-in-an-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 4):

First add the library project as module.

**File->New->Import module**

then add this line to your dependencies in gradle

```
compile project(':yourmodule')
```