# how to add libs dependency from project to module in android studio Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have created an android project its name is a Sample app I also created a library module inside the Sample app project. The sample app has a dependency on other libraries so I have added required jar files inside the libs folder of the Sample app. the same jar files are required inside the module as well.

how can I add the dependency for the module to refer to the sample app's libs folder?
I have tried this below but every time giving a Duplicate copy file exception.

```
repositories {
    flatDir { dirs '../libs' }
}

compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your app's build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile project(':module-name')
}
```

Comment: hi jay, i have added compile project(':module-name') to my app build.gradle. But my issue is i want to use the libraries of the app into my module. means, my app and module wanted to use same dependencies.

Comment: @sathish Check this solution will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170395/how-to-include-a-library-module-dependency-in-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 1):

If you want a library (*.jar / *.aar) to be visible to the entire project, then you will need to make it's location visible to all projects.

Project's gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            // This is where the *.jar or *.aar should be located
            dirs "$rootProject.projectDir/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

With the following directory structure:

```
SampleApp/
|--- app/
|--- libs/
     \--- myLibrary.aar
|--- myModule/
|--- build.gradle (<-- Project's gradle file)
\--- settings.gradle
```

And the following dependencies graph:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
|--- project :myModule
    \--- :myLibrary:
\--- :myLibrary:
```

then

SampleApp's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project (":myModule")
    compile (name: 'myLibrary', ext: 'aar')
    // ...
}
```

myModule's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile (name: 'myLibrary', ext: 'aar')
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Module dependency in android studio, follow below instruction :

You should put your library modules inside the Application Project. In order to specify a module dependency, simply:

```
Right click on Application->Open Module Settings
Click on the '+' icon
Select the root directory for your library module you'd like to add.
Follow the prompts
```

Then, this module will show up in your project. Then, you need to add it to Application as a library dependency. Once again, in your Module Settings:

```
Select your Application module
Select the Dependencies tab on the right
Click the '+' icon on the bottom
Select Module Dependency
Select your desired library module
```

Comment: Hi Jaimin, thanks for your replay. But i am unable to find the checkbox before module name. i would like to add common libraries to both application and its module.

Comment: then, google out it, Hope GoogleBaba will helps you lot..!

Answer (score 0):

In app level build.gradel

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile files('lib/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')

    }
```

Comment: you assume that universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar added in lib folder

Comment: It's **libs**, not **lib**!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **kotlin DSL** add this to **build.gradle.kts** file:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation(project(":your-library-module"))
}
```